# Looking to trigger part of a C# script by external event

Tags: c#, excel, api, webhooks

ill try to keep my question short, littlebit of context:

I'm not a programmer, I work as engineer making configurators. I made a C# (.NET) .exe that uses another program's API to preform actions, right now it does so by me clicking a button on a windows forms application. This is already great, but i'm looking to automate further.

What is my goal? instead of me triggering a part of my script by clicking, i need it to trigger automatically.

Under What condition do i need to trigger? Right now i use Power Automate (previously know as Microsoft flow) to write data to Excel file, when it is finished writing data there, the script is allowed to trigger once.

What ways of achieving this do i see?

1. I could possibly use Excel API to detect a change of values inside my Excel document and trigger the script that way
2. I see i can create a Webhook in Power Automate and send a HTTP push

Again, i am not a programmer so i don't have to knowledge to make a good descision here. Maybe there is other ways to accomplish my goal aswell. I need a bit of direction and reference so i find the right solution and implement it.

Thank you all, if something is unclear or more information is needed, let me know!